# div и padding, отступ для вложенного блока

Tags: php, css, html, padding

Извините за тривиальный вопрос.

Есть div

```
    <div id="bot">
  <?php
      include_once "getFromShukudai.php";
  ?>
</div>
```

В getFromShukudai.php цикл на получение данных из таблицы

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='sample'>";
       echo $row["name"] . $row["message"] ."<br>". $row["timestamp"] .  "<br>";
       echo "</div>";}
```

После добавления в стили кода, отступ  не появляется.

```
.sample{
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Но когда в Ctrl + Shift + I меняю стиль .sample, отступ появляется.
Почему так происходит?

Polnaya versiya

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>HTMLのサンプル</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hello.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top">
    <form  method="POST" action="connectionToShukudai.php">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
  <td align="left" width="100">name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="TextBox" maxlength="550" size="20"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="left" align="right">message</td>
<td> <textarea name="comment" value="TextBox" placeholder="TextBox" maxlength="550" size="20"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="BUTTON"/></td>
  </tr>
</form>
  </div>
  </table>
<div id="bot">
  <?php
      include_once "getFromShukudai.php";
  ?>
</div>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

getFromShukudai.php

```
<?php
//mysqliクラスのオブジェクトを作成
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'ajc0802');
//エラーが発生したら
if ($mysqli->connect_error){
  print("接続失敗：" . $mysqli->connect_error);
  exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM shukudai";
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='sample'>";
       echo $row["name"] . $row["message"] ."<br>". $row["timestamp"] .  "<br>";
       echo "</div>";
}
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

mystyle.css

```
2 lines (21 sloc)  351 Bytes
#top {
    background-color: #666666;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}
#bot{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
}
.sample{
  background-color: white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  style="width: 960px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
body{
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

Comment: а где формируются указанные стили? в отдельном .css-файле? где он подключен?

Comment: Лучше смотреть, сгенерированный html и css. А не как он генерируется.

Comment: Иван, добавлял только фрагменты кода, другие думаю не затрагивают суть. В css подключён, с другими фрагментами вопросов нет.

Comment: Arnial, не уверен, что правильно вас понял, но весь код писал сам. Или если мы говорим о <div class="sample">, которые генерирует функция, то для них я могу в inspect моде установить стиль. Но через css  нет.

Comment: Иван, добавил полную файла. Надеюсь на вашу поддержку.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала у вас ошибка в генерации css класса .sample

```
  border-radius: 5px;
  style="width: 960px;
  padding-left: 40px;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Пользуйтесь редактором кода который умеет автоформатировать(Brackets, Atom ...)
2. Отделяйте HTML и PHP, шоблонизаторы или как минимум функции форматирования (printf).

Из ошибок:

1. Не правильная вложенность у вас

открываються:

`div > form > table`

закрываютья:

`form > div > table`

2. Битые стили смотрите ответ @AndreyFedorov.